# draggable no se aplica a elemento creado mediante append

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

¿Qué puedo corregir para que el método `.draggable()` se aplique correctamente a los elementos creados mediante el botón añadir?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  
  $('.drag_drop').draggable({
    addClasses: false,
    containment: "parent"
  });
  
  $('#add').click(function(){
    $('.parent').append('<div class="drag_drop">Aquí <b>no</b> funciona</div>')
  });
  
});
```

```css
.parent {
  width: auto;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px black solid;
}

.drag_drop {
  font-family: Arial;
  text-align: center;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  border: 1px black solid;
  float: left;
  margin: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="drag_drop">
    Aquí funciona
  </div>
</div>
<br />
<button id="add" type="button">Añadir</button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Esto sucede porque la función de arrastre está configurada para ejecutarse sólo una vez cuando el documento está listo. Por lo tanto, cuando agrega un nuevo nodo al documento, éste no se aplicará al elemento nuevo.

Para esto, tendrías que aplicar un cheque "en vivo" para los nuevos elementos implementados en el documento y luego aplicarlos lo `.draggable()`, lo que podrías hacer con un `.on("DOMNodeInserted ", function ()` pero no vamos a ir por ese camino porque ese es un camino lleno de baches y sensible para cada proyecto.

Para este exacto ejemplo en su pregunta podemos envolver el `.draggable()` en una función, y lo llamamos cuando hay un tecleo en el botón.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    function dragTrack() {
        $('.drag_drop').draggable({
            addClasses: false,
            containment: "parent"
        });
    }
    dragTrack();

    $('#add').click(function(){
        $('.parent').append('<div class="drag_drop">Aquí <b>no</b> funciona</div>');
        dragTrack();
    });

});
```

```css
.parent {
  width: auto;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px black solid;
}

.drag_drop {
  font-family: Arial;
  text-align: center;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  border: 1px black solid;
  float: left;
  margin: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="drag_drop">
    Aquí funciona
  </div>
</div>
<br />
<button id="add" type="button">Añadir</button>
```

Comment: +1 *works like a charm* :D !

Comment: De nada hermano @Jorius . Wubba Lubba Dub Dub! xD

Answer (score 0):

Cuando el navegador interpreta toda la pagina por primera vez se crea un arbol DOM de todos los elementos que estan en ese momento(es por eso que tu primer elemento si funciona pues esta desde que se creo la pagina).

Ahora bien JQuery crea un DOM virtual de la pagina y este no se modifica a menos que refresques, por tanto aunque tu veas que aparecen los cuadros no esxisten en el DOM y por tanto no se les puede aplicar la clase que pones.

¿Qué se puede hacer? la respuesta corta se llama 'Propagación de eventos' y consiste en decirle al padre de estos elementos que ademas existe desde el principio, que cada vez que se le agregue un hijo le diga que debe pertenecer a dicha clase.

En tu ejemplo seria algo como esto:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  
  
  
  $('#add').on("click",function(){
    $('#parent').append('<div>Aqui</div>');
    $('#parent').children().addClass("drag_drop");
    $('.drag_drop').draggable({
    addClasses: true,
    containment: "parent"
  });
   });
  
});
```

```css
.parent {
  width: auto;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px black solid;
}

.drag_drop {
  font-family: Arial;
  text-align: center;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  border: 1px black solid;
  float: left;
  margin: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<div id="parent">
  <div class="drag_drop">
    Aquí funciona
  </div>
</div>
<br />
<button id="add" type="button">Añadir</button>
```